# Table partition is range or interval based

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have to do the data base partition testing, i created the interval partition to the table now if i move the clock for testing, the new partitions are not getting created? Still it is showing the old partitions. Any idea how to resolve this? How to check whether table is range partitioned or interval partitioned in oracle database?

After using the below code for the partition deletion i am getting interval partitioned table as range partitioned.

`SQL> create or replace procedure  partition_delete(var in int) AS
      2       v Date := SYSDATE;
      3       i number;
      4       occurance  number;
      5       l_drop_sql varchar2(2000);
      6  BEGIN
      7  execute immediate ' alter table "sch1"."AUDITS" set interval ()';
      8  execute immediate ' alter table "sch1"."ALERTAUDITS" set interval ()';
      9  -- select the tables that starts with either A or L having cfcc as table owner
      10  for curs in ( select table_owner,table_name,partition_name,high_value from          dba_tab_partitions where table_owner='owner' and REGEXP_LIKE (table_name,'^(A|L)')) LOOP
     11       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT ' || curs.high_Value || ' FROM dual' INTO v; --   Conversion of high_value from long to date
    12       select round(SYSDATE - v) into i from dual; -- finding the difference between    current date and partition creation date
    13       select count(*) into occurance  from dba_tab_partitions where     table_name=curs.table_name;  -- Finding the no of existing partitions to the particular    table
    14       -- occurance>1 indicates table having only one partition is not getting deleted
    15         if i > var  and occurance > 1  then
    16             dbms_output.put_line('The no of days are '||i);
    17             dbms_output.put_line('The table name and partition name are    '||curs.table_name||'and'||curs.partition_name);
    18             l_drop_sql  :='alter table "'||curs.table_owner||'"."'||curs.table_name||'" drop partition '||curs.partition_name||' update global indexes';
    19             dbms_output.put_line(l_drop_sql);
    20             execute immediate l_drop_sql;
    21        end if;
    22  end LOOP;
23  execute immediate 'alter table "sch1"."AUDITS" set interval (NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1,''month''))';
24  execute immediate 'alter table "CFCC"."ALERTAUDITS" set interval (NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1,''month''))';
25  end;
26  /`

Procedure created.

Please help me with it..

Comment: How do you move the clock for testing?

Comment: Please show us some code, CREATE TABLES, SELECTs you've done etc...

Comment: Thanks for the code. So, the procedure runs, and prints out 'ALTER TABLE ... DROP PARTITION...', but the partition is still there?

Comment: hi. after execution i'm getting interval field of other tables as No, it should be Yes right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For interval partitions, the column `INTERVAL` in the data dictionary view `USER_TAB_PARTITIONS` is set to `YES`:

```
SELECT table_name, partition_name, partition_position, INTERVAL, segment_created 
  FROM user_tab_partitions;

  TABLE_NAME  PARTITION_NAME PARTITION_POSITION INTERVAL SEGMENT_CREATED
  MYTABLE     PRE2014        1                  NO       NO
  MYTABLE     SYS_P385       2                  YES      YES
  MYTABLE     SYS_P401       3                  YES      YES
  MYTABLE     SYS_P441       4                  YES      YES
```

Answer (score 2):

To find if a table is interval partitioned, whether or not any partitions based on the interval have been created, you can check `(DBA)(ALL)(USER)_PART_TABLES.INTERVAL`. If it's not NULL this column contains the partitioning interval specified when the table was created or altered to be interval partitioned. If NULL it means that the table isn't interval partitioned.